# yii2 remove optgroup from dropdownlist

Tags: forms, yii2

How can i remove the optgroup from a checkbox field

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'survey_type')->dropDownList([$surveyTypeList],['prompt'=>'Select Survey Type','id'=>'Survey_Type_dropdown']) ?>
```

provides following html

```
<label class="control-label" for="Survey_Type_dropdown">Type</label>
<select id="Survey_Type_dropdown" class="form-control" name="Surveys[survey_type]">
<option value="">Select Survey Type</option>
<optgroup label="0">
<option value="2D">2D</option>
<option value="3D">3D</option>
</optgroup>
</select>

<div class="help-block"></div>
```

Comment: Does a checkbox generate a dropdown?

Comment: sorry, updated question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to send `$surveyTypeList` as a variable, not a array.

Just remove `[]`.

Comment: It helps me a lot